# Scipy, Numpy, Matplotlib Troubles on OSX

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, homebrew

I just installed scipy and numpy using homebrew and pip. I did the following:

```
brew install python
brew install gfortran
easy_install pip
sudo pip install numpy
sudo pip install scipy
```

numpy and scipy are both easily found in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages, but when I open a python shell in the terminal and type:

```
import numpy
import scipy
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

and the same for scipy. What's wrong? Pip seems to think they're installed.

Comment: are you sure that python you are using is the same as the python for which numpy and scipy are installed ?

Comment: After you install python with homebrew, it tells you to add some paths to your `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH`.  If you don't do that, `easy_install` and thus `pip` will be the system python's, not homebrew's.  `numpy` and `scipy` should be installed in `/usr/local/`... for homebrew's python to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python shell you are running from the terminal is probably OSX pre-bundled python and not the one you installed (with numpy & scipy).

You can list the current paths using:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit overkill, but I once wrote a short guide to install Python 2.7.x in OS X. You can find it [here](http://urinieto.com/2012/02/install-python-2-7-x-under-snow-leopard-lion-64-bits/).

The bottom line is that right now you might have two versions of Python installed, and it can be a bit tricky to uninstall only one of them. If you're sure which one is using the right site-packages folder, then delete the other and update your path variables. If not, I'd suggest to follow that guide.

Comment: It looks like you're right, I have two pythons. One is the original that came with my mac, and one is the one homebrew installed in /usr/local. When I type

    which python

I get /usr/local/bin/python, which is the brew install. But as I said above, numpy and scipy are installed with the osx install (I probably didn't edit the path properly and pip installed it wrong. Is this a quick fix by moving some things around, or do I need to reinstall?